# Uncheck check_box only not working with rspec / capybara tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, rspec, capybara-webkit

I have a nested form that has 4 checkboxes. Currently, everything is working in browser, but I can't get the capybara tests to uncheck the checkbox and save.

Using Rails 4.2.2 and latest versions of capaybara-webkit and rspec

**settings.html.erb**

```
  <%= f.fields_for :preferences do |f| %>
    <div class="email-notifications-holder">
      <div class="email-holder">
        <%= f.label :new_match, "Getting a new match each week" %>
        <%= f.check_box :new_match, class: "checkbox new_match_email" %>
      </div>
      <div class="email-holder">
        <%= f.label :match_reminder, "New matches Thursday reminder", class: "match_reminder_email" %>
        <%= f.check_box :match_reminder, default: true, class: "checkbox"   %>
      </div>
      <div class="email-holder">
        <%= f.label :accepted_match, "A Glassbreakers accepted a match", class: "accepted_match_email" %>
        <%= f.check_box :accepted_match, default: true, class: "checkbox"   %>
      </div>
      <div class="email-holder">
        <%= f.label :new_message, "Received a new message", class: "new_message_email" %>
        <%= f.check_box :new_message, default: true, class: "checkbox"  %>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

**edit_account_spec.rb**

```
  it "allows the user to opt out of new match email", :js do
    user = create(:user)
    preferences = create(:preference, user: user)
    sign_in(user)

    visit edit_user_path(user)
    click_tab(t("edit_user.tabs.settings"))

    find(:css, "#user_preferences_attributes_0_new_match").set(false)

    within "#button-container" do
      page.find('.save.main-save-button-edit').trigger('click')
    end



    visit edit_user_path(user)
    click_tab(t("edit_user.tabs.settings"))

    user.preferences.reload
    new_match_email_checkbox = find(".new_match_email")
    expect(new_match_email_checkbox.checked?).to be_falsey
  end
```

I've tried clicking it, unchecking it, checking it, trigger clicking it, wrapping it around a within block, reloading the db, etc.

```
    new_match_email_checkbox = find(".new_match_email")
      within(".email-notifications-holder") do
      page.uncheck('Getting a new match each week')
    end

    new_match_email_checkbox.set(false)
```

Comment: And how do you know it is not unchecking this field? Is there some exception, unexpected behaviour? Have you tried to `save_and_open_page`?

Comment: @BroiSatse yes, i've tried save_and_open_page - when it opens the page the checkbox is still checked!

Comment: your example has some mangled code... that includes a fine and a within as well as the uncheck... I can't tell if you've tried just the basic uncheck without that extra guff. eg just plain: `page.uncheck('Getting a new match each week')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now when you save a user's profile, you must have onboard skills saved or else it will throw an error message when you're trying to click the save button.

part of the user controller

```
  def update
    if update_current_user?(user_params)
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      flash["notice"] =
        "Please choose 3 industries, fields and years of experience."
      redirect_to edit_user_path(current_user)
    end
  end

  private

  def update_current_user?(update_params)
    skills_chosen?(update_params[:user_onboard_skills_attributes]) &&
      current_user.update(update_params)
  end
```

Using save_and_open_page, the error alert wasn't appearing so it was unclear what was happening.  I was able to debug this by trailing the logs while running the tests using:

```
tail -f log/test.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Just using this will uncheck the checkbox

```
   within(".email-notifications-holder") do
      page.uncheck('Getting a new match each week')
   end
```

But you then have to grab the element to test it.

```
new_match_email_checkbox = find(".new_match_email")
expect(new_match_email_checkbox.checked?).to be_falsey
```

Note:
One thing I am unclear about. Are you trying to make this line work?:

```
find(:css, "#user_preferences_attributes_0_new_match").set(false)
```

or are you trying to uncheck the checkbox after you call `user.preferences.reload` ?

Comment: I was showing a few options how I was trying to go about it.  The find(:css, "#user_preferences_attributes_0_new_match").set(false) line was a test.  I also was reloading the database to ensure it saved.  If you look at the answer below, I figured out why it wasn't saving.